# Bold Greek letters in latex section name

Tags: bold, greek, letters, sections-paragraphs

I'm having small trouble with "pi" in section name `\section{ $\pi$ }` in LaTeX. I need to bold `\pi` but I do not know how to do it. I was try to use

```
$\mbox{\boldmath${\pi}$}$,

$\mbox{\mathbf{\pi}}$,

$\mathbf{\pi}$,

$\bm{\pi}$
```

but it doesn't work.
[image: How "pi" look like now]
[image: What I want to achieve]
First image show how it look now, seccond show what I want to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `$\boldsymbol{\pi}$` was not in your list of trials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless using a special font, the macro`\boldsymbol` from `amsbsy` package should do.

(Beware, that math typesetting will make the bookmarks weird if used unless `\texorpdfstring` with appropiate workaround is applied)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\section{Not bold $\pi$}

\section{Bold $\boldsymbol{\pi}$}

\section{Bold \texorpdfstring{$\boldsymbol{\pi}$}{\textpi}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two versions, one without `hyperref`, one with it.

### No `hyperref`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{\protect\boldmath Bold $\pi$}

\end{document}
```

### With `hyperref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\protect\boldmath Bold \texorpdfstring{$\pi$}{\textpi}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How does the `\texorpdfstring{}{}` command works? What does `\textpi` in the second argument does?

Comment: @opisthofulax `\texorpdfstring{1}{2}` uses `1` for normal typesetting, but will use `2` for setting the bookmark text; `\textpi` will print a Greek pi.