# Bold math text in section names

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, sectioning, bold

I have problem with bold math text in sections and subsections. I want to bold this:

```
\subsubsection{Wyniki dla ${}^{222}\mathrm{Radon}$}
```

I tried `\boldsymbol{}` from [THIS SOLUTION](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213563) but it's not working properly because after that I have bolded text in my table of contents too. I want to remove bold mode in my table of contents. Any ideas how to make it?

Comment: I think what you want is `dla \textsuperscript{222}Radon` not in math mode.

Comment: _if_ you want to do this, you should modify your section heading code where it specifies `\bfseries` to also specify `\boldmath`

Comment: @Sigur, it works but how to get mathmode numbers and equal sign without "Z" letter in math mode there?
 `\subsubsection{Wyniki dla pierwiastka o $\mathrm{Z}=123$}`

Comment: So, in this case it would be better to edit your post and show explicitly a math example, like above. The one you gave suggested me only text content produced wrongly with math mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% copied from article.cls, added \boldmath
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\section{zzz}
\subsection{zz}
\subsubsection{Wyniki dla ${}^{222}$Radon}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `\textsuperscript`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\isotope}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1}#2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Wyniki dla \isotope{222}{Radon}}

Wyniki dla \isotope{222}{Radon}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to embolden math in titles (you shouldn't, in my opinion), use `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\bfseries\boldmath}

\newcommand{\isotope}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1}#2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Wyniki dla \isotope{222}{Radon}}

Wyniki dla \isotope{222}{Radon}

\section{Wyniki dla pierwiastka o $\mathrm{Z}=123$}

Wyniki dla pierwiastka o $\mathrm{Z}=123$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want bold math everywhere boldface is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xapptocmd\bfseries{\boldmath}{}{}

\newcommand{\isotope}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1}#2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Wyniki dla \isotope{222}{Radon}}

Wyniki dla \isotope{222}{Radon}

\section{Wyniki dla pierwiastka o $\mathrm{Z}=123$}

Wyniki dla pierwiastka o $\mathrm{Z}=123$

\end{document}
```